# Don't work field type on Drupal custom module

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, field

I'm creating a custom module and content type. And show this items on my page. My module is:

```
function theme_news(){
    global $language;

    $output = '';

    drupal_set_title('News');


    $m_query = db_select("node","n")->extend("PagerDefault")->limit(10);
    $m_query->fields("n",array('nid','title','language'));
    $m_query->condition('status','1',"=");
    $m_query->condition('n.type','news','=');
    //$m_query->condition('n.language',$language->language,'=');
    $m_query->orderBy('n.sticky','desc');

    if(arg(1) == 'latest_news'){
        $m_query->join('field_data_field_etype','fe','n.nid=fe.entity_id');
        $m_query->condition('fe.field_etype_value','ap','=');
        if(arg(2) != ''){
            $m_query->join('field_data_field_myear','fy','n.nid=fy.entity_id');
            $m_query->condition('fy.field_myear_value',arg(2),'=');
        }

    }

    if(arg(1) == 'feature_news'){
        $m_query->join('field_data_field_etype','fe','n.nid=fe.entity_id');
        $m_query->condition('fe.field_etype_value','sp','=');
        if(arg(2) != ''){
            $m_query->join('field_data_field_myear','fy','n.nid=fy.entity_id');
            $m_query->condition('fy.field_myear_value',arg(2),'=');
        }
    }
```

This function creates 2 sub menus and shows the contents in these submenus. Working my code but i don't know, why I don't see field_myear value.

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you solve your task by combining Drupal views and filters, instead of crafting custom SQL queries in your custom module, right away. In most cases this is sufficient, and leads to less headache later.

`condition` clauses should be view filters.

`join`s should be view relationships

and your custom fields should be CCK fields indeed.

Comment: I found problem. Module have hot this div:  <div class="right">
                                <h4>'.$m_detail->title.'</h4>
                                <div class="section">News, 2011</div>
                                <div class="description">
                                    <div How can i fix?

Comment: `div`s are the part of HTML markup, that is displayed through templates processing. The module is a piece of PHP code that is linked to Drupal and gets called in various places when processing the request. What do you mean wich 'module not having div'?

Comment: Views has the ability to include any field into the output. Please, try to achieve your goal by combining stock functionality first, for that writing custom PHP is qiute anti-Drupalish :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use views, create a view with relations, order, fields and all you need,then copy generated sql query by views in your module, this will work.